# Imgur. Get .json of a gallery with specific amount of images

Tags: imgur

I've been able to make requests to get albums from Imgur as with the following request:

```
$http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/18b7b",
    headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Client-ID ********'
}
```

and I get .json with, for example, hundreds of images.

How can I request a specific number of images (for example 2) I want to get from album?